# Difference between const & const volatile

Tags: c, embedded

If we declare a variable as `volatile` every time the fresh value is updated
If we declare a variable as `const` then the value of that variable will not be changed

Then `const volatile int temp;`
What is the use of declaring the variable `temp` as above?
What happens if we declare as `const int temp`?

Comment: You wouldn't use `const volatile int temp;` at block scope (i.e. inside `{ }`), it has no use there.

Answer (score 176):

An object marked as `const volatile` will not be permitted to be changed by the code (an error will be raised due to the `const` qualifier) - at least through that particular name/pointer.

The `volatile` part of the qualifier means that the compiler cannot optimize or reorder access to the object.

In an embedded system, this is typically used to access hardware registers that can be read and are updated by the hardware, but make no sense to write to (or might be an error to write to).

An example might be the status register for a serial port.  Various bits will indicate if a character is waiting to be read or if the transmit register is ready to accept a new character (ie., - it's empty).  Each read of this status register could result in a different value depending on what else has occurred in the serial port hardware.

It makes no sense to write to the status register (depending on the particular hardware spec), but you need to make sure that each read of the register results in an actual read of the hardware - using a cached value from a previous read won't tell you about changes in the hardware state.

A quick example:

```
unsigned int const volatile *status_reg; // assume these are assigned to point to the 
unsigned char const volatile *recv_reg;  //   correct hardware addresses


#define UART_CHAR_READY 0x00000001

int get_next_char()
{
    while ((*status_reg & UART_CHAR_READY) == 0) {
        // do nothing but spin
    }

    return *recv_reg;
}
```

If these pointers were not marked as being `volatile`, a couple problems might occur:

- the while loop test might read the status register only once, since the compiler could assume that whatever it pointed to would never change (there's nothing in the while loop test or loop itself that could change it).  If you entered the function when there was no character waiting in UART hardware, you might end up in an infinite loop that never stopped even when a character was received.
- the read of the receive register could be moved by the compiler to before the while loop - again because there's nothing in the function that indicates that `*recv_reg` is changed by the loop, there's no reason it can't be read before entering the loop.

The `volatile` qualifiers ensures that these optimizations are not performed by the compiler.

Comment: +1 for explanation. And I have a question: what about const volatile methods? If I have a class, which is accessed by many threads (although access is synchronized with mutex) does my const methods also have to be volatile (since some variable could be changed by other thread)

Comment: A simple question: why `const volatile` objects can never be placed in read-only memory? See C11, footnote 132.

Comment: @pmor: The semantics of volatile-qualified objects are implementation-defined.  The Standard gives implementations *blanket* permission to interpret a `const` qualifier on an object that isn't `volatile` as an invitation to place the object in read-only storage, *with no obligation to document such treatment*.  An implementation could specify that the semantics of `volatile` objects vary depending upon whether they are `const`, but *if an implementation doesn't document that `const` affects the behavior of `volatile` objects*, then `const volatile` objects must behave like `volatile` ones.

Comment: @supercat Since "An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects" AND if `const volatile` object is placed in read-only memory, then one may ask: "how this object can be modified in ways unknown to the implementation if it is placed in read-only memory?". However, such a modification is outside of C. Perhaps OS (if any) temporarily removes "read only" attribute, etc. Have a look: https://reviews.llvm.org/D131012.

Comment: @pmor: I see nothing in the text that would forbid an implementation from treating volatile-qualified objects in any manner they see fit, *provided they document it*.  For clang to refuse to place objects there because the Standard supposedly forbids it would be a gross abuse of the Standard, though in line with what I've come to expect from the maintainers of clang.

Comment: @pmor: Do you see anything in the Standard which would contradict an interpretation that allows `const` objects tp be [;aced in a read-only segment if at least one of the following statements is true: (1) the object is not qualified `volatile`, or (2) the implementation is one that documents such treatment for `const volatile` objects?  If an implementation were to specify that all static-duration volatile objects are placed in a read-write segment called "volatiles", the Standard's invitation to place const-qualified objects in a read-only segment would not apply to that implementation.

Answer (score 47):

- `volatile` will tell the compiler not to optimise code related the variable, usually when we know it can be changed from "outside", e.g. by another thread.
- `const` will tell the compiler that it is forbidden for the program to modify the variable's value.
- `const volatile` is a very special thing you'll probably see used exactly 0 times in your life (tm). As is to be expected, it means that the program cannot modify the variable's value, but the value can be modified from the outside, thus no optimisations will be performed on the variable.

Comment: I'd have thought that `volatile` variables are usually what happens when you start messing with hardware, not with other threads.  Where I've seen `const volatile` used is in things like memory-mapped status registers or the like.

Comment: Of course, you're absolutely right, multithreading is just one example, but not the only one :).

Comment: If you work with embedded systems you will see this very often.

Comment: Its not actually that special, I see it all the time in embedded work

Answer (score 34):

It is not because the variable is const that it may not have changed between two sequence points.

Constness is a promise you make not to change the value, not that the value won't be changed.

Comment: Plus one for pointing out that `const` data is not "constant".

Comment: Is there any type of qualifier that completely prevents modification of a variable, both by program and external?

Answer (score 18):

In C, `const` and `volatile` are type qualifiers and these two are independent.

Basically, `const` means that the value isn’t modifiable by the program.

And `volatile` means that the value is subject to sudden change (possibly from outside the program).

In fact, the C Standard gives an example of a valid declaration which is both `const` and `volatile`. The example is:

`extern const volatile int real_time_clock;`

where `real_time_clock` may be modifiable by hardware, but cannot be assigned to, incremented, or decremented.

So we should already treat `const` and `volatile` separately. These type qualifiers can be applied to `struct`, `union`, `enum` and `typedef` as well.

Answer (score 7):

I've needed to use this in an embedded application where some configuration variables are located in an area of flash memory that can be updated by a bootloader. These config variables are 'constant' during runtime, but without the volatile qualifier the compiler would optimise something like this...

```
cantx.id = 0x10<<24 | CANID<<12 | 0;
```

...by precomputing the constant value and using an immediate assembly instruction, or loading the constant from a nearby location, so that any updates to the original CANID value in the config flash area would be ignored. CANID has to be const volatile.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `const` and `volatile` together. For example, if `0x30` is assumed to be the value of a port
that is changed by external conditions only, the following declaration would prevent any possibility
of accidental side effects:

```
const volatile char *port = (const volatile char *)0x30;
```

Answer (score 6):

`const` means that the variable cannot be modified by the c code, not that it cannot change. It means that no instruction can write to the variable, but its value might still change.

`volatile` means that the variable may change at any time and thus no cached values might be used; each access to the variable has to be executed to its memory address.

Since the question is tagged "embedded" and supposing `temp` is a user declared variable, not a hardware-related register (since these are usually handled in a separate .h file), consider:

An embedded processor which has both volatile read-write data memory (RAM) and non-volatile read-only data memory, for example FLASH memory in von-Neumann architecture, where data and program space share a common data and address bus.

If you declare `const temp` to have a value (at least if different from 0), the compiler will assign the variable to an address in FLASH space, because even if it were assigned to a RAM address, it still needs FLASH memory to store the initial value of the variable, making the RAM address a waste of space since all operations are read-only.

In consequence:

`int temp;`is a variable stored in RAM, initialized to 0 at startup (cstart), cached values may be used.

`const int temp;`is a variable stored in (read-ony)FLASH, initialized to 0 at compiler time, cached values may be used.

`volatile int temp;` is a variable stored in RAM, initialized to 0 at startup (cstart), cached values will NOT be used.

`const volatile int temp;` is a variable stored in (read-ony)FLASH, initialized to 0 at compiler time, cached values will NOT be used

Here comes the usefull part:

Nowadays most Embedded processors have the ability to make changes to their read-only non-volatile  memory by means of a special function module, in which case `const int temp` can be changed at runtime, altought not directly. Said in another way, a function may modify the value at the address where `temp` is stored.

A practical example would be to use `temp` for the device serial number. The first time the embedded processor runs, `temp` will be equal to 0 (or the declared value) and a function can use this fact to run a test during production and if sucessfull, ask to be assigned a serial number and modify the value of `temp` by means of a special function. Some processors have a special address range with OTP (one-time programmable) memory just for that.

But here comes the difference:

If `const int temp` is a modifiable ID instead of a one-time-programmable serial number and is NOT declared `volatile`, a cached value might be used untill the next boot, meaning the new ID might not be valid untill the next reboot, or even worse, some functions might use the new value while other might use an older cached value untill reboot.
If `const int temp` IS declared `voltaile`, the ID change will take effect immediately.

Comment: Wow this answer is long

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms,
Value in 'const volatile' variable cannot be modified programmatically but can be modified by hardware. Volatile here is to prevent any compiler optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

We use 'const' keyword for a variable when we don't want to the program to change it. Whereas when we declare a variable 'const volatile' we are telling the program not to change it and the compiler that this variable can be changed unexpectedly from input coming from the outside world.