# const volatile doubled in production code

Tags: c, constants, keyword, semantics, volatile

I am currently working with production code in ANSI-C, which is partly getting generated by a very intransparent toolchain (so I could not find any clear information about it).

Somewhere in the generated code the following happens:

```
extern const volatile int16 * const volatile Varray[20];
```

And the access to it:

```
int16 myValue = *Varray[var];
```

It works, this is not part of the question. I just want to know why the `const volatile` is written before AND after the datatype `int16 *`.

Comment: i prefer write it `extern int16 const volatile * const volatile Varray[20];` ;)

Comment: Is this the right duplicate? *I just want to know why the const volatile is written before AND after the datatype int16 *.* - OP asked this. @FelixPalmen

Comment: The `const` keyword tells the compiler a value should not be changed inside the code where the declaration is. The keyword `volatile` tells the compiler that the value might be changed outside the code where is the declaration. The first declaration informs the compiler about the pointer values, the second declaration informs the compiler about the pointed values.

Comment: @coderredoc I think this question is answered implicitly when reading the linked duplicate. You just have to know what the qualifiers mean in the different places.

Comment: @coderredoc if the question is more semantic (like *why does the pointer **and** the data need to be volatile and const*?), it needs more context, in which case it **could** be reopened.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: No it's ok. I guess OP would get a lot of help from dup itself. Thanks and good job.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592762/difference-between-const-const-volatile

Comment: @coderredoc well Stargateur spotted it, I just "hammered" because I think it's enough for answering the question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Yes I admit. That's alright. I will delete the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you all, the marked question did solve my headaches. Should've searched the issue without 'volatile', then I probably would've found the duplicate.

Comment: Excuse me, in my explanation you have to exchange "The first declaration" and "the second declaration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern const volatile int16 * const volatile Varray[20];
```

This just means that both the pointer and the value are "const volatile".

So, Varray is an array of const volatile pointers which will store const volatile int16's