# __builtin_types_compatible_p(t1, t2) and pointers to qualified types

Tags: c, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

The gcc documentation says that `__builtin_types_compatible_p(t1, t2)` "ignores top level qualifiers (e.g. const, volatile)", and indeed it does:

```
__builtin_types_compatible_p(int, const int)     returns 1
__builtin_types_compatible_p(int, volatile int)  also returns 1
```

I do not know what it means by "top level qualifiers", but pointers to things-which-are-compatible, are reported as *not* compatible:

```
__builtin_types_compatible_p(int *, const int *)     returns 0
__builtin_types_compatible_p(int *, volatile int *)  also returns 0
__builtin_types_compatible_p(void *, void *)         returns 1
__builtin_types_compatible_p(void *, const void *)   returns 0
```

which is, frankly, a surprise :-(

Can anyone provide a reason for this ?  [Is my surprise a symptom of ignorance ?]

---

FWIW: I can work around this using `__typeof__()`, thus:

```
__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(*(void*)0), __typeof__(*(const void*)0))) returns 1

typedef int*       pi_t ;
typedef const int* pic_t ;
__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(*(pi_t)0), __typeof__(*(pic_t)0))) returns 1
```

Since `__typeof__()` accepts both an expression and a type, I have a macro:

```
#define Types_Compatible(_a, _b) \
  __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(_a), __typeof__(_b))
```

to slightly reduce the clutter.

Comment: regarding your observation about `const` and `volatile`, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4592762/645128) for the reason they are ignored.

Comment: Top level. `__builtin_types_compatible_p(int *, int *const )` , `__builtin_types_compatible_p(int *, int *volatile)` , `__builtin_types_compatible_p(int *, int *restrict const volatile)` etc.

Comment: If you just want to ask «What is «top-level cv qualifiers»?», why do it in a such intricate way?

Comment: OK... the question was not direct enough :-(  What I meant to ask is: if `int` is "compatible" with `const int`, then why is `int *` *not* "compatible" with `const int *` ?  And the answer appears to be that "compatible" is to do with compatibility of actual argument types and formal parameter types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` and `const int` are compatible as everywhere an int is expected (eg as a function parameter) a `const int` can be given. And, importantly, vice versa. The `const` and `volatile` only affect the variable, not the value.

That is **not** the case for `int*` and `const int*`. If a function requires an `int*` you can *not* supply a `const int*`. If you try that you will get an 'incompatible types' error. For pointers the `const` and `volatile` refer to the *value*, not the variable. (In most cases, it depends on where you put the `const`)

And your "workaround" just derefences the pointer so it gets rid of the pointer, so it ultimately answers a different question. It determines if the types pointed to are compatible, which is different from the pointer type itself.

Comment: OK, I see the error in my thinking.  I was focusing on the compatibility of the final (pointed to) rvalue (which dereferencing, as you say, gets at).   As you say, `const int*` cannot be passed to a function which takes `int*`.  But `int*` can be passed to a function which takes a `const int*`.  If this is (part of) what "is compatible with" (*icw*) means, then `t1` *icw* `t2` does not imply `t2` *icw* `t1`.  And  `__builtin_types_compatible_p()` seems to return (`t1` *icw* `t2`) && (`t2` *icw* `t1`).  FWIW: gcc does not think `int8_t` *icw* `int`, but clang does !

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion，type T1 is ompatible with type T2 means when you have two variable T1 a and T2 b, then you can assign a = b and at the same time b = a.