# where is the practical use for const char*,volatile const char*,char*const. example of applications will help understand better

Tags: c, embedded

```
const char*

volatile const char*

char *const
```

In c under what circumstance is it used? an example will help understand better.

Comment: `constant` does not exist in C

Comment: I would advice to learn at least C beasic syntax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @0___________ Did you mean "beastic" syntax? ;-)

Comment: constant is const in c, i meant const

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between const & const volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592762/difference-between-const-const-volatile)

Answer (score 1):

`const char *` (and `char const *`, both are equivalent) are used to point to characters that are constant, i.e. the string can't be modified.

Example:

```
const char string1[] = "foo";  // Create a constant, unmodifiable string
const char string2[] = "bar";

const char *s = string1;
// s[0] = 'o'; ERROR: Attempting to modify the constant data
s = string2;  // Okay, makes s point to another constant string
```

---

`char * const` make the pointer variable itself constant, the pointer can't be modified to point somewhere else. The string contents can be modified though.

Example:

```
char string1[] = "foo";
char string2[] = "bar";

char * const s = string1;  // Initialize to point to string in string1
s[0] = 'o';  // Okay, string1 is now "ooo"
// s = string2;  ERROR: Attempting to modify a constant variable
```

---

These `const` qualifiers can be combined:

```
const char string1[] = "foo";
const char string2[] = "bar";

const char * const s = string1;  // Initialize to point to string in string1
// s[0] = 'o'; ERROR: Attempting to modify the constant data
// s = string2;  ERROR: Attempting to modify a constant variable
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Someprogrammerdude has covered the language implications of `const` qualifier I will focus on some implementation aspects

Embedded (especially microcontroller) programmers need to control where the data is placed. If you have a lookup table or data which does not change you want to put it into the FLASH memory and not waste the precious RAM.

Most (known to me) embedded implementations will place `const` data in the `.rodata` segment which usually is physically located in the non-volatile memory (mainly FLASH).

after edit:

- `const char*` - pointer is not `const`, data referenced by the pointer is `const`
- `const char const *` - syntax error - means nothing
- `const char * const`  - pointer is `const`, data referenced by the pointer is `const`
- `volatile const char*` - pointer is not `const`, data referenced by the pointer is `const` but is side effect prone. It means that you cant change that data, but something can. As an example - the read-only hardware register mapped into the address space.
- `const *char` - it is wrong syntax and it means nothing

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no `constant` in C so I assume you mean `const`.
2. `const char const *` is the same as `constant char *` so it makes no sense to repeat the `const`
3. `const *char` is not legal C syntax

Anyway - your main question seeems to be

> Why and when should I use `const` in my code

There are several reasons. Using `const` gives your compiler some extra information about what you want to do. The compiler can make a number of decisions based on that information like doing some optimization, deciding where in memory to place your object and even catching programming bugs.

Another benefit is that you can provide the same information to users of your code. For instance if you write a function that I'm going to use and do it like:

```
void foo(char * string);
```

I can't know whether `foo` will change the contents of `string`. I'll have to read some additional documentation to find out.

But if you do

```
void foo(const char * string);
```

I know that your function `foo` will not change the `string` that I pass to it. Further, I would know that it's safe to pass a string literal to that function. In other words - by using `const` you have given me some extra information in the function proto type and thereby made it easier to use your code.

Another benefit is that it can help you catch mistakes. Let's say you design the function `foo` so that it shouldn't modify `string`. One year later you (or a co-worker) need to make some updates to the function. Meanwhile you have forgotten (or your co-worker didn't realize) that `foo` shouldn't change `string` and therefore do stuff like `string[8] = 'A'`. If you originally declared `foo` using `const`, the compiler will issue an error for that code and thereby help you to avoid mistakes.