# adding NOP before trying to read the register value

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, riscv

Is adding a `nop` a good idea to add some delay before reading from the register address again in order to get the expected value and exit while loop?
Or is it okay to keep on reading the register until `read_reg_val != 1` in a RISC-V machine in order to improve the performance?

My thought process was Solution 1 is a better idea to wait for say 1 clock cycle instead of reading the register unnecessarily as in Solution 2.

What would be the pros and cons with both the solutions?

Solution 1

```
uint32_t read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
while (read_reg_val)
{
  asm("nop");
  read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
}
```

Solution 2

```
uint32_t read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
while (read_reg_val)
{
  read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
}
```

Comment: Adding a NOP sounds like a bad idea.  If the compiler doesn't do it of its own accord, it shouldn't be necessary for you to add one manually.  You might need to worry about memory barriers if you're sharing memory between processes and/or threads.  The rules for RISC-V might be different, but generally, you shouldn't try to outsmart the compiler — you'll usually lose.

Comment: You may want: `asm("nop")` --> `ask volatile ("nop\n" ::: "memory")` to prevent the compiler optimizer from eliding or reordering the block. But, it probably won't do much even with this fix.

Comment: If you have a RISC-V processor supporting `Zihintpause`, you could use a [`pause` instruction](https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-isa-manual/latest/zihintpause.html) to slow down the spin loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is common in hardware-related programming that GPIO registers and similar may need several CPU ticks to stabilize. For example on classic microcontrollers you may write to a data direction register first to set a port as input or output, and then the hardware may need some 100-200ns to stabilize before you can access the actual GPIO port. It is then common practice to add a couple of NOP between the data direction access and the port access. And none of that has anything to do with the compiler - it's hardware requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible to answer without knowing the nature of the register. Some context is necessary.

For example on classic microcontrollers you may write to a data direction register first to set a port as input or output, and then the hardware may need some 100-200ns to stabilize before you can access the actual GPIO port. It is then common practice to add a couple of NOP between the data direction access and the port access.

Taking things further to the extreme, if the register is a data register from some serial bus peripheral or ADC, then it might take many milliseconds before it gets updated. But in such situations there is always a corresponding flag register which you should poll or trigger on by interrupt, rather than busy-waiting until new data appears. Same thing with DMA.

Keep in mind however that loading the value into a CPU register or the stack, then polling that value, takes time in itself.

---

Unrelated to your question, the `const` in the expression
`uint32_t read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr)));` 
is nonsense and fills no purpose. Remove it.

You can de-clutter the code into this 100% equivalent one:

`uint32_t read_reg_val = *(volatile uint32_t*)reg_addr;`

Comment: It's not nonsense, it's just overly parenthesized (and, yes, cluttered), like `return (0);` which can be written more simply as `return 0;` instead.

Comment: @ErikEidt The const part is nonsense since it has absolutely no effect what-so-ever except confusing the reader.

Comment: `const volatile` sounded like nonsense to me at first, but apparently there can be a [legitimate use for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592762/difference-between-const-const-volatile). Not needed in this example though.

Comment: @pmacfarlane In this context it is nonsense because of lvalue conversion. In other situations it can be perfectly sensible, like when dealing with data stored in eeprom/flash.

Answer (score 6):

The NOP should not be necessary unless the datasheet of your specific device recommends it.

In some rare cases, I can imagine you would want to have some NOPs in case you are using something like a DMA (direct memory access) module to transfer data and you don't want the CPU to take up an excessive amount of time on the system bus, slowing down the DMA.  The system will likely work either way though.

Comment: The main intention of solution 1 was to avoid unnecessary register reads and rather  wait for few clock cycles to give some time for the expected value to be updated in the register.

Comment: You haven't explained why you care about "unnecessary reads" or why waiting is good so you're probably just worrying about nothing.  The main effect of your "solution" is to just make the program bigger, and probably slower too.  You should probably replace all that code with `while (*reg) {}`.

Comment: @pavikirthi: Why is it desirable to poll the I/O device less often?  Does that save power, or does each read attempt actually slow down the device's progress toward getting a value ready?  Or make it start again?

Comment: @Peter Cordes - The main goal was to improve the speed. I was thinking trying to read the value from the specific address repeatedly would have impact on the performance.

Comment: I think you're wrong about that.  Meanwhile, adding the NOP in there actually does slow it down, because the CPU might be executing the NOP at the time when it should be loading the register and seeing that it is zero.  Also, adding the NOP increases the code size, meaning less useful code can fit inside any kind of caching or prefetching done by the system, which slows it down further (at least a little).

Answer (score 0):

You selected an answer, and this one may not be any different really.  In short you are making too many assumptions about what is going on to then assume the effect of the nop.  First off, it's not a clock, what kind of system are you running on?  The pipe tries to average a clock but...

So let's look at this a bit and ponder:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

#define reg_addr 0x12345678

void fun0 ( void )
{
    uint32_t read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
    while (read_reg_val)
    {
      asm("nop");
      read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
    }
}

void fun1 ( void )
{
    uint32_t read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
    while (read_reg_val)
    {
      read_reg_val = (*((volatile const uint32_t *)(reg_addr))); 
    }
}


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun0-0x2>:
   0:   0001                    nop

0000000000000002 <fun0>:
   2:   12345537            lui x10,0x12345
   6:   67852583            lw  x11,1656(x10) # 12345678 <.LBB1_1+0x1234565e>
   a:   c181                    beqz    x11,a <fun0+0x8>

000000000000000c <.LBB0_1>:
   c:   0001                    nop
   e:   67852583            lw  x11,1656(x10)
  12:   e181                    bnez    x11,12 <.LBB0_1+0x6>

0000000000000014 <.LBB0_2>:
  14:   8082                    ret

0000000000000016 <fun1>:
  16:   12345537            lui x10,0x12345

000000000000001a <.LBB1_1>:
  1a:   67852583            lw  x11,1656(x10) # 12345678 <.LBB1_1+0x1234565e>
  1e:   e181                    bnez    x11,1e <.LBB1_1+0x4>
  20:   8082                    ret





Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   123457b7            lui x15,0x12345
   4:   6787a783            lw  x15,1656(x15) # 12345678 <.L9+0x1234564c>
   8:   c799                    beqz    x15,16 <.L1>
   a:   12345737            lui x14,0x12345

000000000000000e <.L3>:
   e:   0001                    nop
  10:   67872783            lw  x15,1656(x14) # 12345678 <.L9+0x1234564c>
  14:   ffed                    bnez    x15,e <.L3>

0000000000000016 <.L1>:
  16:   8082                    ret

0000000000000018 <fun1>:
  18:   123457b7            lui x15,0x12345
  1c:   6787a783            lw  x15,1656(x15) # 12345678 <.L9+0x1234564c>
  20:   c791                    beqz    x15,2c <.L9>
  22:   12345737            lui x14,0x12345

0000000000000026 <.L11>:
  26:   67872783            lw  x15,1656(x14) # 12345678 <.L9+0x1234564c>
  2a:   fff5                    bnez    x15,26 <.L11>

000000000000002c <.L9>:
  2c:   8082                    ret
```

clang vs gcc.  If you did not know already the two have a different interpretation of volatile (you can read up on the use of volatile in general).

Also in the above clearly allowing for compressed instructions.

```
000000000000001a <.LBB1_1>:
  1a:   67852583            lw  x11,1656(x10) # 12345678 <.LBB1_1+0x1234565e>
  1e:   e181                    bnez    x11,1e <.LBB1_1+0x4>
```

How does your particular core work, and first off you did not specify one, these days I assume every other engineer in college is making a risc-v core as part of a class, where it might have been mips in the past.  Then, whether a company rolled their own or purchased the IP, then how it it integrated into the system.  Compressed instructions create this unaligned or in risc-v speak misaligned problem above.  Which as documented, with compressed instruction support you are allowed to have these misaligned 32 bit instructions.

What is the size of your fetch?  One word?  Two words?  four?  What alignment?  Does it use a 16 bit bus and units of halfwords?

As fast and clean as your processor IP might be, you are likely memory bound not processor bound (been decades since we were really processor bound).  Particularly if this is an MCU, where the flash you are likely running out of tends to be half the clock rate of the core, folks think it is a good idea to max out the clock rate on their mcus rather than tune it so that makes it no faster you have to add wait states to keep the flash accesses below the max.

Assuming word fetches like a number of ARM mcu cores do (some do half and some are optional for the chip vendor at compile time), we fetch at 0x18 then at 0x1C bnez is a conditional and the core may not be that smart so a fetch of 0x20 is likely happening as well, then ideally sometime before 0x24 is fetched the loop branches backward, you lose some time to the pipe but that may be in the noise when doing the fetch from 0x1C.

Being somewhat optimistic that the flash is half the rate of the core, then 6 clocks per loop for the fetching plus some pipeline cost for the instructions, which could add to that, depends on the depth of the pipe.  But then you are likely reading a peripheral.  The peripheral section of the chip is further away, and possibly in a slower clock domain, and depending on the peripheral even if in the same clock domain may take some number of clocks, may be several maybe a dozen.

```
000000000000000c <.LBB0_1>:
   c:   0001                    nop
   e:   67852583            lw  x11,1656(x10)
  12:   e181                    bnez    x11,12 <.LBB0_1+0x6>
```

In this case we got lucky and the alignment is such that if for example we are fetching words this is still two fetches plus the extra per loop, you technically incur some extra time for the nop but you are also suffering the branch effects on the pipe, so is the nop free?   The number of clocks to do the fetching relative to the core, and then the load from the peripheral, the nop may be free and do nothing to the timing of the loop.

If this landed differently though

```
000000000000000e <.L3>:
   e:   0001                    nop
  10:   67872783            lw  x15,1656(x14) # 12345678 <.L9+0x1234564c>
  14:   ffed                    bnez    x15,e <.L3>
```

You are fetching 0x08, 0x10 and 0x14 and 0x16, so an extra fetch per loop because of the alignment so that may be two extra clocks just from the fetch, then add in the load from the peripheral, etc etc etc.  So you may see the nop in this case cause a couple of clocks per loop and maybe, maybe not due to the pipe another clock by having the extra instruction.   But the load from the peripheral likely dominates the timing of the loop.

Thus far this assumes a 32 bit fetch.  If the fetch is 64 bits or 16 bits then you work through that.  If you have a cache you have other performance issues with that.  A flash cache/pre-fetcher may burn more clocks or help you, etc etc.

The difference of opinion of what volatile means overall the extra instruction but it is likely buried in the noise, but depends on how many times through the loop you had to go.

I have worked with external peripherals like an ADC that is off chip on a bus, and that logic is dealing with the requests to read the status, when properly reading the status first then reading the data value after the status says it is okay.  And have seen that if you poll these too fast, the overall design of that device is such that it gets too busy dealing with your polling that it cannot spend as many clocks on the task you are waiting for it to do and it may never actually convert or it may take much much longer.  So for a peripheral like that you need a delay in your polling to not overload the device from its job.  One would hope this is documented, but...You know, reality...I would not expect to see that in an mcu, but you might see that in a phy or something since they often have processors in them (8051s, etc).  I would not expect a phy to have the problem I have seen with this other ADC, but you never know.

More so with high performance architectures like ARM and mips and risc-v (vs high overhead like x86), the alignment of a loop has a direct effect on the performance as shown above and now you know what to look for and do you can and should be able to easily perform that party trick of moving a loop one instruction or two in address space and dramatically changing its performance.  Simply relying on the compiler and linker to place these for you, your overall performance of an application can change in strange and random ways depending on how many time critical loops you have and how each change you make affects them.

Code that may be a thousand miles away from the time critical loop may cause the whole application to slip by a halfword or word and move where that loop lands relative to the fetch line as I call it.  This is easier to demonstrate on cores that fetch say 4 or 8 words at a time (and those may have branch prediction which itself has a sweet spot within the loop as to how that helps/hurts performance, making the same machine code run in even more different number of clock cycles), but can be demonstrated on some systems with a smaller fetch, as shown above with a word size fetch against a ISA with halfword sized instructions or like risc-v with unaligned/misaligned word instructions.

Because of how trivial it is to take the same machine code and vary the performance on the same hardware, benchmarks are BS as I like to say, but in this context, it is not possible to determine from the question as written if the nop has any effect.  You have to benchmark it on your specific system, including alignment and flash wait states or run from ram instead of flash and on and on to see if the nop actually has an effect.  Also compiler version and compiler differences in how the high level language code is implemented, etc, etc, etc.

NOP is encoded as ADDI x0, x0, 0

C.NOP expands to nop

So in the specific implementation is the core smart enough to actually look for a nop and maybe not do anything or is it burning one or two pipe stages to read x0 twice and do the add?  And do the writeback?  It can be tricky but you might be able to actually time this with your core, or not.  The core may see after decode that it is a nop and skip execution or at least to keep the pipe going not go through a full multi-clock add.  Especially if the pipe is backed up waiting on the slow fetches from flash.

If your logic supports compressed but you did not build for it then you can see what that could do to you.  And/or if the core does not support compressed.  On an mcu, with say word sized fetching then you do not necessarily have the fetch line effects of alignment, you would definitely have an extra fetch per loop, but, is it in the noise. (the flash logic may have something that might hide, or hurt, performance based on alignment)

I am currently working on a system where the risc-v core is half clocked, so that the alignment thing can be handled at the system clock so the core itself is a bit slow but other parts of the system are actually faster, including the memory such that you never are waiting on fetches, they are always perfectly on time or a clock early. Processor bound or peripheral bound.  The pipe is short so branches are quite expensive but forward or back or this or that determines how many clocks it takes it is not always X clocks. (the same direction/situation is always X but there are multiple situations).

Go read Michael Abrash Zen of assembly language.  Available for free, everything above and more covered there.

Bottom line, the nop likely has no effect here; the load likely dominates the loop and the fetching of course.  As shown above you have a 50/50 chance of the fetch of nop being free, then it is a case of how the pipe is constructed and how the nop is implemented.  If this is a system on a chip the number of clocks for the load is likely a handful or more, but the nop, if measurable, likely does not affect the peripheral itself, you would want/need a much bigger delay, but it is unlikely.

Now as mentioned in the accepted answer DMA, assuming that the DMA is actually in the background (never assume that some systems the DMA means the processor stalls until the DMA transaction is complete, you have to know your system) then the more peripheral bus activity you generate interferes with the spare bus cycles the dma has to use, again if that is how this system works.  It may also be that the processor stalls sometimes and the dma stalls sometimes depending on who manages to control the bus next and how long they take and how they are arbitrated.  When using dma on an mcu for example you want the dma to be higher priority and stall the processor otherwise you easily lose data to/from the peripheral.  Your spi or i2c or PWM gets ugly if you let the processor have higher priority.  If you are wanting to count clocks and push your system you have to figure this out.... per system (even two chips from the same vendor).

I have only added a little more color to the already accepted answer, which is nice and concise and has the same conclusion: not possible to answer.  Just covering the comment that you are or might be adding a clock when, maybe you are not or maybe it is three or seven or...